# MicrosoftEntityFrameworkCore is unable find migrations from the assembly

Tags: database, sqlite, xamarin.android, entity-framework-core

I am using entity framework core Ver. 2.2.4, and I am maintaining a separate assembly for maintaining ef generated migrations. During the application startup, when I try to perform `context.Database.Migrate()`, I am getting the following message in the output log

```
No migrations were found in assembly 'MyProject.Core'.
```

I have included `optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(GetConnectionString(), builder => builder.MigrationsAssembly("MyProject.Core"));` to load the appropriate assembly to find the migrations, but no luck. Any Idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the EF Core source code, I figured out what the issue was. The problem was with my application db context class i.e. `AppDbContext:DbContext`. I had this class in my core project marked as abstract and later I was deriving from the class in the android project to define connection string. Looks like EF Core will ignore all the migrations marked with `[DbContext(typeof(AppDbContext))]` attribute containing abstract db context types. Once I made my db context class concrete, my migrations started working.

Answer (score 0):

Reference your migrations assembly from your project.

If you can't because it causes a circular dependency, set the output path of your migrations assembly to your main project's directory: (or otherwise copy it there)

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
 <BaseOutputPath>..\MyStartupProject\bin\</BaseOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```